# Finding continuous data from a table for months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which has month data in INT `April=4`, `May=5` and so on. I want those records which have continuous data. My table is as follows. So if a record has discontinuous data, it should not be returned.

Continuous data means those records which having continuous four month. If records are there for `4,5,6,7` or `5,6,7,8` or `6,7,8,9` months then that record should come in result of a ID. If there records for a ID has `4,5,8,9` in month field this is discontinue data for me.

Initial query:

```
select ID, month from table1 where month in (4,5,6,7,8,9) group by month;
```

Initial Data:

```
PK  ID   month   value
1   1     4      400
2   1     5      200
3   1     6      300
4   1     7      400
5   2     5      400
6   2     6      200
7   2     7      100
8   2     8      400
9   3     4      200
10  4     5      800
11  5     6      800
12  5     7      100
13  5     8      700
14  5     9      900
15  6     4      100
16  6     5      200
17  6     8      500
18  6     9      600
```

Result:

```
PK  ID   month   value  
1   1     4      400    
2   1     5      200    
3   1     6      300    
4   1     7      400
5   2     5      400
6   2     6      200
7   2     7      100
8   2     8      400
11  5     6      800
12  5     7      100
13  5     8      700
14  5     9      900
```

My database is MySQL.

I have months from `April(4)` to `Sept(9)`

Comment: What do you mean by continous data.. Paste the initial data and expected result

Comment: Continuous data means those records which having continuous four month. If records are there for 4,5,6,7 or 5,6,7,8 or 6,7,8,9  months then that record should come in result of a ID. If there records for a ID has 4,5,8,9 in month field this is discontinue data for me.The result what I want is shown above.

Comment: cant you do it on your front-end? in php this can be solved very quickly

Comment: What about if you have _more_ than 4 months of continuous data?  I don't know enough about MySQL to give a good answer here, but I think something along the lines of how `ROW_NUMBER()` tends to get implemented in this db would probably work.

Comment: lets say I have maximum four rows for any ID. ROW_NUMBER() is in sql server.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query this will work I hope!

```
SELECT ID, Month 
    FROM table1 WHERE month in (4,5,6,7,8,9)
    GROUP BY ID, Month 
    HAVING count(ID)>3
```

kindly let me know this is working or not

Comment: This is wrong. even those who have 4,7,8,9 will be included in the result.

Comment: Because the result is need like the ID>3. so if we are giving order by even it will not take the continuous data.